# How to add a number to a field in ms access?

Tags: java, sql

Im trying to add the number 1 to a certain field. How could i manage to do that? Ive tried it but i can never get it to add 1. My ms access table column is set to Number not text.

```
if (s2.equals(box1Text)) {
                        if (s3.equals(box2Text)) {
                            if (s5.equals(currentWinner)) {
                                String sql = "UPDATE Table2 "+ "SET Score = ? " + "WHERE Better = '" + s1+"'";
                                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                                //points made here
                                if (s4.equals(betScore)) {
                                    stmt.setString(1, "+1");//how could i add 1 to the field?
                                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                                } else {

                                }
```

Comment: You'll need the original value, you would then increment the the value and apply it to the field. It might be better to use setObject instead of setString

Comment: How could i do that? Would i need to make a new statement? like SELECT?

Comment: Assuming you haven't alp ready read it, probably

Comment: How would i select a specific field? Instead of selecting all of it?

Comment: Select {field name} from {table}....

Comment: You also try something like UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = Column1 + 1, but I'm not sure if it would work in MS Access

Answer (score 0):

First you do something that is regarded as bad practice : you construct your query by adding the **value** of a parameter in the string.

```
String sql = "UPDATE... >+ s1 +<..."
```

Please nether do that (what is between `>` and `<`) when programming seriouly, but allways use `?` to pass values.

Second, SQL can do the job for you :

```
String sql = "UPDATE Table2 SET Score = Score + 1 WHERE Better = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, s1);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

(`try`, `catch`, tests and other details omitted for brevity)